# Eigenvectors of a $2\times 2$ Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I wish to calculate the eigevalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix:

> $$ \begin{bmatrix}
>     \frac{\displaystyle \epsilon}{\displaystyle 2}       & \frac{\displaystyle \delta}{\displaystyle 2}  \\
>     \frac{\displaystyle \delta}{\displaystyle 2}       & - \frac{\displaystyle \epsilon}{\displaystyle 2} 
> \end{bmatrix} $$

I get that the eigenvalues are,

> $$ \lambda = \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \delta^2}. $$

The eigenvectors are given by:

[image]

The eigenvectors are written in Dirac's BraKet notation.

I am not sure how the eigenvectors have been computed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\ket#1{\mathinner{\rvert{#1}\rangle}}$For a symmetric matrix, eigenvectors that correspond to different eigenvalues are orthogonal. This makes the situation particularly simple in the $2\times2$ case. If you choose a unit eigenvector for one of the eigenvalues, it can be represented as $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)^T$ for some angle $\theta$ relative to an orthonormal basis, or in BraKet notation, $\cos\theta\ket{0}+\sin\theta\ket{1}$. The corresponding unit eigenvector for the other eigenvalue is simply this rotated by $\pi/2$, or $-\sin\theta\ket{0}+\cos\theta\ket{1}$.

To find the angle $\theta$ we can proceed by diagonalizing the matrix: $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac\epsilon2&\frac\delta2\\\frac\delta2&-\frac\epsilon2\end{bmatrix}=R\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}R^T$$ where $R$ is the matrix of a rotation through an angle of $\theta$. If you multiply this out and equate corresponding matrix elements, you end up with the equations $$\begin{align}(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)\sqrt{\epsilon^2+\delta^2}&=\epsilon\\2\cos\theta\sin\theta\sqrt{\epsilon^2+\delta^2}&=\delta.\end{align}$$ Applying the double-angle formulas and dividing one equation by the other yields $$\tan{2\theta}=\frac\delta\epsilon.$$

Underneath the hood, this is essentially the same solution as [Joel Cohen’s](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1887083/265466), since there’s an isomorphism between $\mathbb C$ and conformal $2\times2$ matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvectors $x_i$ for a matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are calculated by solving $Ax_i = \lambda_i x_i$ or equivalently $(A-\lambda_i I)x_i = 0$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Is this enough help, or were you past this point already?

Comment: Yeah, I know this but I am not sure how to get the eigenvalues expressed in the form given above.

Comment: In the notation you mentioned, I  think $|0>\ = (1, 0)^T$ and $|1>\ = (0,1)^T$ so that means you just have to split up the eigenvectors you find into its coordinates.

Comment: @Sanderr you are exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

It may help here to identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$ (identifying $|0\rangle$ with $1$ and $|1\rangle$ with $i$). In that setting, denoting $\omega = \frac{\epsilon+ i \delta}{2}$, your matrix is that of the linear map $u : z \mapsto \omega \overline{z}$.

Finding the eigenvectors of the matrix amounts to finding non zero complex numbers $z$ such that $\omega \frac{\overline{z}}{z}$ is a real number (this real number being the associated eigenvalue). We may assume $z$ to be of norm $1$ by scaling. Write $\omega$ in polar form as $\omega = \lambda e^{2i\theta}$ (here, we write the argument as $2\theta$ for convenience). We can see that $z = e^{i\theta}$ and $z=ie^{i\theta} = e^{i(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2})}$ are solutions (with eigenvalues $\pm\lambda$ respectively).

Geometrically, the map $u$ is the composition of a scaling of factor $\lambda$ with a reflection whose axis is generated by $e^{i\theta}$, and the eigenvectors are along the axis or perpendicular to it.